# Solving some double integrals

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{x}^{2} e ^{\frac{x}{y}} dy  ~dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi /4} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\cos ~y}{\cos~x }~ dy  ~dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi /4} \int_{y}^{\pi /4} \frac{\cos~2x }{ x}  dx  ~dy$$

I need to answer above integrals.

Can you help me?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? Give some context.

Comment: perhaps start by drawing the region out and see if there is any other way to write down the limits

Comment: Study the section of your textbook on Fubini's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints for you to understand, justify and complete**:

$$\begin{align*}
&\bullet\;\;\int_{-2}^2\int_x^2 e^{x/y}dydx=\int_{-2}^2\int_{-2}^y e^{x/y}dxdy\\{}\\
&\bullet\;\;\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^x\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}\,dydx=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_y^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}\,dxdy\\{}\\
&\bullet\;\;\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_y^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos 2x}x\,dxdy=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^x\frac{\cos 2x}x\,dydx\end{align*}$$